# Vaadin Maven Plugin tries to compile subversion directory as a theme

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have an example project created using -

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application \
    -DarchetypeVersion=7.2.5 -Dpackaging=war \
    -DgroupId=com.Example -DartifactId=ProjectA
```

During the maven compilation, the compile-theme goal tries to compile the subversion directory.

```
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:7.2.5:compile-theme (default) @ UIEngine ---
[INFO] Updating theme VAADIN/themes/bootstrap
[INFO] Theme "VAADIN/themes/bootstrap" compiled
[INFO] Updating theme VAADIN/themes/.svn
[ERROR] /home/gpn/workspace/ProjectA/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/.svn/styles.scss could not be read!
[INFO] Theme "VAADIN/themes/.svn" compiled
```

Is there any method to tell maven to ignore .svn directory or to compile only certain themes?

Thanks and Best Regards,
GPN

Answer (score 4):

Add `<theme>bootstrap</theme>` to the configuration of the vaadin-maven-plugin in your pom.xml. After that the plugin will only compile the given theme.

Comment: It worked, thanks, but what about if I want to compile more than one theme?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a newer version of SVN (1.7 or later) to checkout your source then there will no longer be any `.svn` directories in the working copy.